# jQuery : Prevent event to fired on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using Blueimp plugin for uploading multiple files. Here is the **main.js** :

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'index.cfm/uploads/',        
        maxFileSize: 5242880,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt|csv|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx)$/i
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            'includes/blueimp/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
        });
    }

    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        var fileList = $.trim($("#hdnFileList").val());

        if (fileList.length == 0) {
            $("#hdnFileList").val($.trim(data.files[0].name));
        } else {
            fileList = fileList + "," + $.trim(data.files[0].name);
            $("#hdnFileList").val(fileList);
        }
    }).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        Remove($("#hdnFileList"), data.files[0].name);
    }).bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        //Remove($("#hdnFileList"), data.files[0].name);
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            if (!file.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                console.log("PASS");
            } else {
                console.log("FAIL");
            }
        });
    }).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        if (typeof data.result.files == "undefined") return;

        Add($("#hdnUploaded"), data.result.files[0].upFile);
        Add($("#hdnUploadedClientFile"), data.result.files[0].name);
    });

    //On upload fail remove for Upload queue
    var Remove = function (elem, filename) {
        var fileList = $.trim(elem.val());

        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            var arrFiles = fileList.split(",");

            for (var i = 0; i < arrFiles.length; i++) {
                if (arrFiles[i] == filename) {
                    arrFiles.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            elem.val(arrFiles.join());
        }        
    }

    //On upload done add to uploaded queue
    var Add = function (elem, filename) {
        console.log(filename);

        var fileList = $.trim(elem.val());

        if (fileList.length == 0) {
            elem.val($.trim(filename));
        } else {
            fileList = fileList + "," + $.trim(filename);
            elem.val(fileList);
        }
    }
});
```

The code from line #5 - #11 is of concern (rest code is for completeness). The initialization of the object **fileupload** fires a (involuntary) GET request to the **url: 'index.cfm/uploads/'** which I don't want to fire on page load.

The same request is properly fired as POST when I click a button, and it works fine.

The **PROBLEM** is that the GET request on page load is undesirable as it is fired without any arguments and the server-side code handles it as an exception & returns an error message which is properly handled and displayed on the page. But the request should not be fired on PageLoad, and should be made only when file upload button is clicked. So I want to prevent the request to be made on PageLoad.

**NOTE** - I checked the plugin's author's demo page, and the problem exists on his page too.

Comment: I still not quite sure I understand. Can't you just use a different event handler, like `click`, instead of `ready` or `load`?

Comment: @ForeignObject - This is just the "fileupload" object being initialized. Off-course I have an click event handler that takes care of the upload part. But this GET request is what the object initialization is what I don't want.

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted below?

Comment: @ForeignObject - I have already implemented that. My question is on a different track.

Comment: What about using a flag, `isLoaded = false`, then initializing the function after the page has loaded and `isLoaded` is truthy?

Comment: @ForeignObject - I will try that, once I am back to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide the url to the **fileupload object** on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'url',
        'index.cfm/uploads/'
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this points you in the right direction — from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin, towards the bottom:

### How to start uploads with a button click

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
            .appendTo(document.body)
            .click(function () {
                data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                data.submit();
            });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        data.context.text('Upload finished.');
    }
});
```

});

### OR

set a flag and then initialize the `fileupload` plugin after the page has loaded ( with another event/ JS Promise, etc ) like below ( roughly implemented )

```
var isLoaded = false;

if ( isLoaded ) {

   $('#fileupload').fileupload({
       url: 'index.cfm/uploads/',        
       maxFileSize: 5242880,
       acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt|csv|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx)$/i
    });

 }
```